# Create if not exist Firebird 1.6

Tags: sql, firebird

Офф. [ФАК](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq69/) только для 2.0 и выше. в 1.6 не работает.
Как создать таблицу если только она не создана?
И как аналогично удалить таблицу если она создана?
баз много, таблица может быть а может не быть.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте реализовать через хранимую процедуру. В официальном факе [описано](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq373/) как это сделать при добавлении столбца в таблицу.